# Apache Over SSL - Request Entity Too Large , mod_security not installed

Tags: apache2

I'm having a problem with Request Entity Too Large when posting large data via AJAX to a Php program.

I don't think mod_security is installed or enabled as there is no /etc/modsecurity folder and i can't find anything with the name when searching the server for files.

The domain is running on a virtual host in ssl.conf and all works fine except this issue with posting large amounts of data.

The strange thing is, i also have the same server setup on a local development virtual machine also running on SSL over a self signed certificate and the problem doesn't happen on the local machine; it's just the live dedicated server where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be many things, but you have this `LimitRequestBody` directive in Apache which is defined as such:

> This directive specifies the number of bytes from 0 (meaning unlimited) to 2147483647 (2GB) that are allowed in a request body. See the note below for the limited applicability to proxy requests.
>
> The LimitRequestBody directive allows the user to set a limit on the allowed size of an HTTP request message body within the context in which the directive is given (server, per-directory, per-file or per-location). If the client request exceeds that limit, the server will return an error response instead of servicing the request. The size of a normal request message body will vary greatly depending on the nature of the resource and the methods allowed on that resource. CGI scripts typically use the message body for retrieving form information. Implementations of the PUT method will require a value at least as large as any representation that the server wishes to accept for that resource.

While the Apache default is `0` (no limit), your own installation may have a different value.

You have also other directives that limit things like that (see all starting with `Limit` on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html), including header lengths and contents.

You will need to have a closer look at your Apache configuration. You can also increase verbosity and you should then have more details in your logfiles.

Comment: Thanks, actually worked it out, was the setting in .htaccess in the end. Security plugin for WordPress added it , took ages to work it out since apache config was all good.